# Problem with Rangy adding multiple spans when applying a class

Tags: rangy

this is a posible duplicate of: [Rangy: Adding multiple highlights for the same piece of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092337/rangy-adding-multiple-highlights-for-the-same-piece-of-text)

But this question got no answers.

The problem is that the Rangy API puts a lot of span tags when applying a class in an element that already had a class placed by Rangy, such as color or background-color.

i.e:

```
<p><span class="redBackground">texto de ejemplo para probar rangy</span></p>
```

becomes (when i apply other background colors):

```
<p><span class="redBackground">text</span><span class="blueBackground">o de ejemplo</span><span class="orangeBackground"> para proba</span><span class="orangeBackground">r ran</span><span class="redBackground">gy</span></p>
```

in the case of "orangeBackground" class, i dont see the reason of having multiple spans, is it possible to force Rangy not to place so many spans?